# Does having sirens on while having a wanted level increase the chance of police finding me?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

If I am evading police whilst I'm in a vehicle that has sirens I turn them off as I am not sure if police would follow the noise in the hopes of finding me. It would make more sense they are searching for the car I am in rather than the sound of sirens in the area the crime was reported from, but then again it also seems like it could be a bad idea to hide down an alleyway with sirens blaring.

Comment: I believe at one point this was a thing, but I'm not sure if it is any longer. However, keep in mind that the game does have mechanisms to detect noise made by the player, thus increasing the detection radius of your character.